# Unable to find sub element using array list

Tags: android, arrays, automation, appium

Unable to find sub element.
Hey ,
I'm writing Android app automation using Appium.
I have a test that I need to check that the three buttons in a certain place contain the correct text.

I'm trying to get the three buttons with the for loop.

Here you can see the elements I bring to UiAutomatorViewer.

There is the main element that i find.

[![enter image description here][1]][1]

There is the sub elements that i tried to find:

[![enter image description here][2]][2]

[![enter image description here][3]][3]

[![enter image description here][4]][4]

There is some code that i tried but i get error that says:

```
org.openqa.selenium.NoSuchElementException: An element could not be 
located on the page using the given search parameters.
*** Element info: {Using=xpath, 
value=android.widget.TextView[@index='1']}
```

According to element info, i got right xpath of each element.

What am I doing wrong?

```
    List<MobileElement> buttons = 
 driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@bounds='[170,946][910,1689]']"));
            for (int i = 1; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
                MobileElement button = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("android.widget.TextView[@index='"+i+"']"));
                System.out.println(button.getText());
            }


  [1]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/qhpBr.png
  [2]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/8owI4.png
  [3]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/SFaQb.png
  [4]: https://i.stack.imgur.com/QxpPw.png
```

Comment: guess you are missing out `//` in xpath while finding MobileElement button. `"//android.widget.TextView[@index='"+i+"']"`

Comment: Hi Prerna ,
I'm added the // symbols, but it still not working=[
`MobileElement button = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("./android.widget.TextView[@index='"+i+"']"));`

Comment: Could you please add the HTML again? I do not see it in the question anymore.. let me try to figure out what other issue might be there..

Answer (score 0):

You need to add `.` to your XPath expression in order to make it work:

```
MobileElement button = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("./android.widget.TextView[@index='"+i+"']"));
```

> `.`   Selects the current node

References:

- [XPath Syntax](https://www.w3schools.com/xml/xpath_syntax.asp)
- [XPath Axes](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/XPath/Axes)
- [XPath Operators & Functions](https://docs.experitest.com/pages/viewpage.action?pageId=40044727)

Comment: Hi Dmitri T.
I added a . to the xpath, but still have the same issue.

There is the new code :
'List<MobileElement> buttons = driver.findElements(By.xpath("//android.view.ViewGroup[@bounds='[170,946][910,1689]']"));
        for (int i = 1; i < buttons.size(); i++) {
            MobileElement button = (MobileElement) driver.findElement(By.xpath("./android.widget.TextView[@index='"+i+"']"));
            System.out.println(button.getText());
        }'